# Is there is any property to Check popup blockers of browser enabled or not? like navigator.cookieEnabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is `navigator.cookieEnabled` to check whether cookies enabled or not. Likewise is there any property to check if popup blockers of browser enabled or not?

Just looking for single line property like **navigator.cookieEnabled**

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCookie(){
    var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;
    if (!cookieEnabled){ 
        document.cookie = "testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1;
    }
    return cookieEnabled || showCookieFail();
}
```

// Popup Check

```
 function checkForPopBlocker() {
     var testPop = window.open("", "","width=100,height=100");
     if (testPop === null) {
        alert("Please disable your popup blocker.");
     }
     testPop.close();
 }
```

Comment: Hey tq @Zulqurnain Huda, but i asked to check popup blockers enabled or not...!

Comment: Please check second answer

Comment: Again tq for efforts, even i have some javacript code to check, but here am just looking some property just like navigator.cookieEnabled, just one line

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this blog for detailed explanation https://davidwalsh.name/popup-block-javascript. However, below is the absolute code. I hope this should work..

```
var windowName = 'userConsole'; 
var popUp = window.open('/popup-page.php', windowName, 'width=1000, height=700, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable');
if (popUp == null || typeof(popUp)=='undefined') {  
    alert('Please disable your pop-up blocker and click the "Open" link again.'); 
} 
else {  
    popUp.focus();
}
```

Comment: Tq @Abirami Murukesan for efforts, even i have some javacript code to check, but here am just looking some property just like navigator.cookieEnabled, just one line